clipboard doesnt show up at all
i got this popup, now the clipboard only shows
this how to fix?
i tried restarting but it didnt work
i can copy & paste, it just doesnt show up in the clipboard (it is enabled in settings and ive tried turning it on and off)
ive tried other troubleshooting reccs like running it as admin and such but none of it worked

Please read How do I ask a good question? and then edit and update your question. At the moment it misses even the basic info required to understand your problem.
